# vbscript how to force the IE scroll bars to lock to the bottom

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, scrollbar

Im using IE as a form to provide feedback of running processes.  As the processes update they eventually go beyond the window size.  What I want to have happen is that the IE window will lock to the bottom of the page instead of the top, so as data appears it scrolls down - almost like a 'tail' function

This is what I use to create the IE window that I pump data into

```
Sub ExplorerWindow(strStage)

        Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","IE_")

        objExplorer.Navigate "about:blank"
        objExplorer.ToolBar = 0
        objExplorer.StatusBar = 0
        objExplorer.Width = 600
        objExplorer.Height = 700
        objExplorer.Left = 350
        objExplorer.Top = 100
        objExplorer.Visible = 1

        Do While (objExplorer.Busy)
        Loop

        Set ObjDoc = objExplorer.Document

        ObjDoc.Open
        ObjDoc.Writeln "<html><h1><center>DO NOT TOUCH THE KEYBOARD OR MOUSE</center></h1>"
        objDoc.Writeln "<body bgcolor='white'>"
        objDoc.Writeln "<font face='Lucida Console,Courier,mono'>"
        objDoc.body.style.cursor = "wait"

        strDescription = "Stage " & strStage

        objDoc.Writeln "<h1>" & strDescription & "</h1><hr>"
        Call LogTheEvent(b2k, strDescription)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  When I write data to the form I use

```
objDoc.Writeln <Data Here>
```

Now I just add the following line to the sequence

```
objDoc.Body.scrollTop = objDoc.Body.scrollTop + objDoc.Body.scrollHeight
```